# SIM ICCID number - Flutter

Tags: flutter, iccid

How to get the ICCID number of a sim card inside a mobile in flutter? Is there any package that can be made use of to retrieve the same? I looked for it but could find packages to get the number only but not the ICCID number.

Comment: I could not find a way to retrieve ICCID. Instead, I used  [sim_data_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/sim_data_plus) package to uniquely identify a sim. @Anand

Comment: We can get only sim's mobile number only

Comment: Is there any way to find call from call log is sim1's call or sim2's call